# How to overlay more than 2 divs (with bootstrap if possible)?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to overlay 4 divs on one another with z-index

It seems to works for only 2 divs

When I try to blur the main bg (1st bg) it's affecting all of the divs

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

HTML-

```
<div class="bg1">
  <div class="bg2">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text-layer">
        <p>Eleven years ago, wizards rejoiced all over the world, and Muggles (non-magic folk) were confused. They celebrated because He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named was defeated. In other words, Voldemort (the evilest wizard around) killed Harry Potter's parents,
      but for some strange reason, he couldn't kill little baby Harry. Now Voldemort seems to have disappeared. Overnight, baby Harry has become a hero – "The Boy Who Lived." Having lost his family and home, Harry also has become an orphan. Dumbledore
      (the principle of Hogwarts School of Wizardry and Witchcraft), Professor McGonagall (a teacher at Hogwarts), and Hagrid (a groundskeeper at Hogwarts) find a home for baby Harry with his Muggle extended family, the Dursleys.</p>

        <p>Cut to present day, when ten-year-old Harry lives with his super-mean aunt and uncle and their son Dudley. When they go to the zoo for Dudley's birthday, Harry encounters a sympathetic snake. He's able to speak to the friendly reptile and somehow
      seems to have removed the glass from its cage, so it can go back to Brazil. After the trip to the zoo, mysterious letters start arriving for Harry. His uncle, Mr. Dursley, is furious and tries to keep them from Harry. But the letters keep arriving
      at such a rapid rate that, the evening before Harry's eleventh birthday, his uncle takes the whole family to a deserted island to escape all of the mail.</p>

        <p>They can't hide for long, though; Hagrid shows up on Harry's birthday to deliver the letter, and the news that Harry's a wizard and has been admitted to the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. The next day he takes Harry to shop for school
      supplies at Diagon Alley, where Harry learns more about the wizarding world. He meets Malfoy (a bully) and Hogwarts' new Defense Against the Dark Arts professor, Quirrell. Harry also buys his first wand. Sweeeet. Hagrid also picks up a mysterious
      package at Gringotts, the goblin bank.</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS-

```
.bg1 {
 position: relative;
 background-image: url("http://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Flowers/Sun_Flower_HD_Image.jpg");
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 filter: blur(4px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
}

.bg2 {
 background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg");
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-filter: opacity(30%);  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
 filter: opacity(40%);
}

.overlay {
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.text-layer {
 height: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 z-index: 300 !important;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle- [jsfddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwcnfvm7/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change your HTML structure a little bit to achieve what you want. My idea is to have the `text-layer` being the top layer, and set backgrounds and overlay layers to be its 100% width and height (via `absolute` positioning).

```
<div class="text-layer">
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg2"></div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="text-content">
        <!-- I just added container here for fun -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- text -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the styles.

**Note:** `z-index` only works on positioned elements, i.e., `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

```
.text-layer {
  position: relative;
}

.bg1, .bg2, .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bg1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Flowers/Sun_Flower_HD_Image.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: blur(4px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.bg2 {
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(30%);
  /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: opacity(40%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 3;
}

.text-content {
  /* 
   * I have to set this to relative in order to use z-index, because the 
   * default is static. See the note.
   */
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/101650/

Comment: Aah.. beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!
Can you tell me where to use absolute, relative and fixed? I'm a lil confused..

Comment: @nonliving: yes, please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .bg1 {
            position: relative;
            background-image: url("http://www.hdnicewallpapers.com/Walls/Big/Flowers/Sun_Flower_HD_Image.jpg");
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: -1;
            overflow: hidden;

        }
        .bg1:before{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width : 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: inherit;
            z-index: -1;

            filter        : blur(10px);
            -moz-filter   : blur(10px);
            -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
            -o-filter     : blur(10px);

            transition        : all 2s linear;
            -moz-transition   : all 2s linear;
            -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
            -o-transition     : all 2s linear;
        }

        .bg2 {
            background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg");
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            position: relative;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-filter: opacity(30%);
            /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
            filter: opacity(40%);
        }

        .overlay {
            z-index: 2;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        .text-layer {
            height: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            z-index: 300 !important;
        }
```

```html
<div class="bg1">
    <div class="bg2">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text-layer">
                <p>Eleven years ago, wizards rejoiced all over the world, and Muggles (non-magic folk) were confused. They celebrated because He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named was defeated. In other words, Voldemort (the evilest wizard around) killed Harry Potter's parents,
                    but for some strange reason, he couldn't kill little baby Harry. Now Voldemort seems to have disappeared. Overnight, baby Harry has become a hero – "The Boy Who Lived." Having lost his family and home, Harry also has become an orphan. Dumbledore
                    (the principle of Hogwarts School of Wizardry and Witchcraft), Professor McGonagall (a teacher at Hogwarts), and Hagrid (a groundskeeper at Hogwarts) find a home for baby Harry with his Muggle extended family, the Dursleys.</p>

                <p>Cut to present day, when ten-year-old Harry lives with his super-mean aunt and uncle and their son Dudley. When they go to the zoo for Dudley's birthday, Harry encounters a sympathetic snake. He's able to speak to the friendly reptile and somehow
                    seems to have removed the glass from its cage, so it can go back to Brazil. After the trip to the zoo, mysterious letters start arriving for Harry. His uncle, Mr. Dursley, is furious and tries to keep them from Harry. But the letters keep arriving
                    at such a rapid rate that, the evening before Harry's eleventh birthday, his uncle takes the whole family to a deserted island to escape all of the mail.</p>

                <p>They can't hide for long, though; Hagrid shows up on Harry's birthday to deliver the letter, and the news that Harry's a wizard and has been admitted to the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. The next day he takes Harry to shop for school
                    supplies at Diagon Alley, where Harry learns more about the wizarding world. He meets Malfoy (a bully) and Hogwarts' new Defense Against the Dark Arts professor, Quirrell. Harry also buys his first wand. Sweeeet. Hagrid also picks up a mysterious
                    package at Gringotts, the goblin bank.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why it doesn't show bg1 image? I think bg2's opacity is still affecting the text layer..

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not showing on my pc.. Also why is the opacity of bg2 is affecting the text layer?